# how to setup multiple vhost in one file

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

i moved from fedora to ubuntu 16.04.

in fedora i could list endless vhost in one file. where as in ubuntu i must create a new file for each vhost. i already have my list with all vhosts in it. is the re any way to do this in ubuntu?

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@apecenergy
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apecenergy.co.uk/public_html
    ServerName www.apecenergy.co.uk
    ServerAlias apecenergy.co.uk 
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/apecenergy-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/apecenergy-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@apecenergy
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/plumbing_sites/crouchendplumber.co.uk/public_html
    ServerName www.crouchendplumber.co.uk
    ServerAlias crouchendplumber.co.uk 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just ubuntu's shortcut organization for apache. It will work the same way. You can save that one long file with multiple vhosts to your `sites_available` folder under `filename.conf` then enable them all at once.

```
sudo a2ensite filename
```

Although this is convenient at first, you will be better off in the long run if you take the time to split them apart.

Comment: i did try i get this message Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.